# Over Curent protection for multiple consumers

Tags: power-supply, led, protection, short-circuit, circuit-protection

[image]

While designing a light fixture I came across an issue.
The fixture is powered by a single ACDC unit that generates 24V.
The fixture has around 50 LED elements that are connected to the power source.
If a single LED element has a short circuit then the over current protection on the PSU kicks-in and power is cut off to all the other LEDs making it very hard to locate the faulty LED and replace it.

What would be the best (and cheapest) way to add another short circuit protection per LED element that will kick in *before* the PSU shuts down so only the faulty LED will get disconnected from the power bus? I thought of adding a PTC but I'm afraid it will take time for it to kick-in as it is temperature based and it will 'loose the race'.

- I don't want to change the PSU and it is impossible (and unsafe) to switch off the over current protection. Most quality PSUs comes with this feature built in.
- I can't change the LED driver and LED (G4 LED)
- For mechanical reasons I can't change the topology of the connections.

Comment: Have you considered a resettable "poly-fuse"?

Comment: Your diagram shows that each LED driver has a constant current output therefore, how can it take more current if the LED fails?

Comment: Poly-fuse is PTC. The issue with a poly-fuse is the relatively long time it takes to switch. I also considered a simple old fashion glass cartridge fuse but this will enforce me to take the whole light fixture apart as there is no place to hide the fuse.

Comment: If the LED (or driver) fails as a short circuit the current can jump

Comment: While a polyfuse is arguably a class of PTC device, it's not a 'thermistor' like a traditional PTC is. It reacts faster and has a significantly sharper response curve. If you've preemptively ruled out polyfuses just because you think all PTC devices are the same then you've probably made an error.

Comment: I though they were the same. I will give a polyfuse a try